# Scroll event listener function gets triggered as many as how far I scrolled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

```
  const handleReadChat = useCallback(() => {
    const entry = refEntries.current;
    if (
      entry.scrollTop > entry.scrollHeight - 800 &&
      activeRoom &&
      conversations?.content?.length > 0 &&
      activeRoom.unread
    ) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(readConversationByRoom(activeRoom.id));
        console.log("executed", activeRoom.unread);
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [activeRoom, conversations?.content]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const entry = refEntries.current;
    const handleScrollButtonVisibility = () => {
      if (entry.scrollTop < entry.scrollHeight - 800) {
        setShowScrollButton(true);
      } else {
        setShowScrollButton(false);
      }
    };

    entry.addEventListener("scroll", handleScrollButtonVisibility);
    entry.addEventListener("scroll", handleReadChat);
    return () => {
      entry.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScrollButtonVisibility);
      entry.removeEventListener("scroll", handleReadChat);
    };
  }, [handleReadChat]);
```

So the code above I'm using for a chat app that I'm building, where if that room has unread messages, and if I scroll to the bottom of the page, it will trigger the `handleReadChat` function and set the read status to `true`. However, I noticed that when I scroll, it gets triggered as many times as how far I scrolled. I think if I scrolled 200px down, it will get triggered 200x. Is there a better way to refactor my code?

Comment: Maybe scrollend event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scrollend_event

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [scrollend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scrollend_event) then within the callback check if the scroll is at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable to limit the scroll using window.innerheight.

Create an if statement that say when innerheight reaches 200 it will stop "rolling".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).